# Detecting advanced boolean search operators in a PHP string

Tags: php

Most of the users of my website are not familiar with how to correctly use advanced search operators.  The following is just one example of what I see in the database:

lavender + burns+

Instead of using +lavender +burns

I'm trying to trigger error messages so that they can correctly learn how to do an advanced search.  I already have an error that appears when they try to use quotes around a single word instead of a phrase.  Now I'm trying to come up with an error that displays when they don't use the + correctly.  My code can detect if there is a plus sign, but I just need some help on how to tell if the + appears right in front of a word or after.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do:

```
if (preg_match('/\w\+/', $string)) {
    // a plus was found following a word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples you have above, the regex operators `^` and `$` will be of interest to you.  They match the beginning and ends of lines.  For instance, `^+[a-zA-z]*` will match what you want and `[a-zA-Z]*+$` will match what your users input.

Read more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write a nice regular expression that will do this, but you might want to try something simple like this.

```
$queryArray = explode(' ', $rawQuery);
if (count($queryArray)) {
    if ('+' === $queryArray[0][0]) {
        // + is in front of first word in query
    }

    $lastWordInQuery = $queryArray[count($queryArray) - 1];
    if ('+' === $lastWordInQuery[strlen($lastWordInQuery) - 1]) {
        // + is at the end of last word in query
    }
}
```